# C++ get the difference between two vectors

Tags: c++, vector

imagine you got 2 vectors:

```
vector<int> ar1, a2;

ar1 = {1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6};
ar2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

how to do something like this in a good way (using C++) ?

```
b = ar1 - ar2
// b = {1,3,5}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: What do you mean "like this"? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)

Comment: @RichardWieditz `set_difference` has not the behavior described in your post!

Comment: @RichardWieditz But if you needed `std::set_difference` then what is "vector without other vector" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Columbo: Are you sure it's wrong? [Demo at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6SUKD3)

Comment: @Blastfurnace I didn't read the reference properly, i.e. "Equivalent elements are treated individually", pardon me.

Comment: If the second vector has a 7 in it what is supposed to happen?

Comment: i don't see why set_difference is wrong

Comment: what is the unclear part of the question ? I got a vector {1,2,3} and another vector {1,2}. I want to do {1,2,3} - {1,2} giving me a {3} as result.

Comment: @RichardWieditz, Probably the fact that the first one has duplicates.

Comment: duplicates means in this case ... ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
//from cppreference
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
 
int main() {
 
    std::vector<int> v1 {1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6};
    std::vector<int> v2 {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> diff;
    //no need to sort since it's already sorted
    //but you can sort with:
    //std::sort(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1))

    std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(),
        std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
 
    for (auto i : v1) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << "minus ";
    for (auto i : v2) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << "is: ";
 
    for (auto i : diff) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I want to up-vote this post, but i cant ! This is exactly what i wanted to do !

Comment: Meh - it's an example from cppreference, so not really worth upvoting!

Comment: cppreference is the reference I want to use ?

Comment: if i google a std::anything.. always seems to be cppreference that comes up first. I've found them pretty useful

Comment: @RichardWieditz: http://cppreference.com and http://cplusplus.com are the two most common non-official references. Many of us prefer http://cppreference.com. http://cplusplus.com used to have a less than stellar reputation but has gotten better over time.

Comment: Absolutely right - set_difference requires sorted vectors. Most of the related std algo's require just that. Performing the same operation on unsorted vectors you could populate a std::set with the contents of both vectors and then do a size comparison to verify if they are indeed the same.

Comment: As a side note - Richard presents an example with sorted vectors - so the answer is perfectly reasonable for the question. Not sure why that deserves a downvote..

Comment: @GeorgeNewton you could also use `std::multiset` which allows multiple keys with equivalent values.

Comment: Would not std::back_inserter be more appropriate for this example?

Comment: this answer will not work in the case of an unsorted array. What to do in that situation??

Comment: std::sort(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1))

Comment: This doesn't work if the vectors contain a type for which the `<` operator isn't overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193182/4284627) only works if you have sorted vectors of a type for which the `<` operator is overloaded.

If you have a type for which the `<` operator is overloaded but the vectors aren't sorted, you need to sort them first:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v1 {3,1,3,2,4,1,5,5,6};
std::vector<int> v2 {6,1,4,5,2,3};
std::vector<int> diff;
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
```

If the `<` operator isn't overloaded, you can write your own comparator:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<SomeType> v1 {...};
std::vector<SomeType> v2 {...};
std::vector<SomeType> diff;
const auto cmp = [](const SomeType &a, const SomeType &b){
    //Should return true if a is considered strictly less than b
};
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), cmp);
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), cmp);
std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()), cmp);
```

However, if writing your own comparator is not trivial, it might be easier to simply write your own function to find the difference between the vectors:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> vectorDifference(const std::vector<T> &v1, const std::vector<T> &v2){
    //Make the result initially equal to v1
    std::vector<T> result = v1;

    //Remove the elements in v2 from the result
    for(const T &element: v2){
        const auto it = std::find(result.begin(), result.end(), element);
        if(it != result.end()){
            result.erase(it);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```